# How to conditionally add(or modify) ContextConfigLocation to web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web.xml

I need to modify the web.xml in my project after checking some parameters. My *contextConfigLocation* parameter in web.xml is as follows:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
  classpath:*/test-spring-config.xml classpath:*/someContext.xml classpath:applicationContext.xml classpath:databaseContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now I need to add *classpath:securityContext.xml* to my *contextConfigLocation* in web.xml upon checking some condition before my application is loaded in tomcat.
I've tried doing this in my *applicationInitializer* class which implements *ServletContextListener* as follows(part of the code is shown):

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements ServletContextListener
{ 
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
{ ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();
      if(someConditionIsTrue){
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:securityContext.xml");
        appContext.setServletContext(sc);
        appContext.refresh();
        sc.setAttribute("org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT",appContext);
}
```

But this is not working because I'm again loading the context in my web.xml as

```
<listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Can somebody suggest how to deal with this problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApplicationInitializer should extend ContextLoaderListener for your scenario and listener class should be pointing to ApplicationInitializer in web.xml

Answer (score 2):

After a few days of struggle, I was able to do this by creating a *CustomContextLoaderListener* class which extends *ContextLoaderListener* and override its *createContextLoader* method which now returns a *customContextLoader* as follows:

```
@Override
protected ContextLoader createContextLoader(){
return new CustomContextLoader();
}
```

The *CustomContextLoader* class extends ContextLoader and I've override its *customizeContext* method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void customizeContext(ServletContext servletContext, ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext){
super.customizeContext(servletContext, applicationContext);
String[] oldLocations = applicationContext.getConfigLocations();
String[] newLocations;
if(conditionIsTrue){
newLocations = new String[oldLocations.length+1];
for (int i = 0; i < oldLocations.length; i++) {
        newLocations[i] = oldLocations[i];
    }
newLocations[oldLocations.length] ="classpath:securityContext.xml";
}else{
    newLocations = new String[oldLocations.length];
    newLocations = Arrays.copyOf(oldLocations, oldLocations.length);
}
applicationContext.setConfigLocations(newLocations);
}
```

Do not forget to add the *customContextLoaderListener* class in your web.xml.

```
<listener>
<listener-class>com.abc.px.customContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is it! This way I can conditionally set my context in web.xml. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I believe that's what i mentioned in my answer ;)

Comment: Yeah! I digged everything above from your answer. Thanks mate!